# SAML LOGOUT Error when user clicks on logout after inactivity of more than hour or 2

Tags: spring-saml

We are using Spring SAML Solution :

we are having issues while SAML LOGOUT We invoke URL : /saml/logout without any inactivity it works normally and logout the user

but when we invoke same urlafter 1 or 2 hours of inactivity it thows stack overflow error below are the logs

Please help Thanks in advance

<[ServletContext@236322167[app:PS module:smp path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception java.lang.StackOverflowError at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getRequestURI(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:230) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getRequestURI(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:230) at org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil.processFilter(SAMLUtil.java:201) at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.requiresLogout(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:175)

Answer (score 0):

Also using spring SAML security extension for our e-commerce website and we are also facing same issue. From tests we did, it seems to happen when we force the global logout form our SP after the IdP session alread expired. But like previous post , assuming that the issue is on SP spring side.

thanks for any feedback from everyone as this error is not very elegant on our website.

Stéphane